# How to get option text not value with only static options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How to extract the text of an option (select) when I am having hard coded options only?

```
<select ng-change="addLanguage( )" ng-model="language">
<option value=af>Afrikaans</option>
...
(374563 options more)
...
</select>
```

So how can I get "Afrikaans" in my `addLanguage()`? Please note, the options are hard in the html, no json.

Comment: What are you asking I'm a little confused...

Comment: in `language`there is `stored`. How can I get the option text `Afrikaans`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<select id="languageSelect" ng-change="addLanguage( )" ng-model="language">
<option value=af>Afrikaans</option>
...
(374563 options more)
...
</select>

<script>
function addLanguage()
{
     window.alert(document.getElementById("languageSelect").options[document.getElementById("languageSelect").selectedIndex].innerHTML); //this will have text in it
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to your select tag:

```
<select id="taal" ng-change="addLanguage( )" ng-model="language">
<option value=af>Afrikaans</option>
...
(374563 options more)
...
</select>
```

and then it'll be real easy like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("taal");
var taal = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text;
```